# Continuity and Box topology in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am trying to understand discontinuity of the the following function:

$$
h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^\omega \quad h(x):=\left(x,\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{3},\ldots\right)
$$
where $\mathbb{R}$ is given with standard topology and $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is given with box topology. The answer says, since $h^{-1}(B)=\{0\}$ for $$B=(-1,1)\times \left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\times \left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right)\times\ldots\;,$$

$h$ is discontinuous. However, I think that $h^{-1}(B)=(-1,1)$ since if $a\in (-1,1)$ then $\frac{a}{n}\in\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for all $n$, hence $h(a)\in B$. Can anyone point me out my mistake in the previous argument? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right and $h^{-1}(B) = (-1,1)$ which is open.

The authors may have meant a different set like $$B' = (-1,1) \times \left(-\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}\right) \times \left(-\frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{9}\right) \times \dots \times \left(-\frac{1}{n^2}, \frac{1}{n^2}\right) \times \dots$$
This should give $h^{-1}(B') = \{0\}$ and show that $h$ is discontinuous.